# Range to be calculated and grouped

Tags: php, sql

I am having set of values ex: **title A** is having value **27.32**, **title B** is having **value 27.33** and **title C** is having **value 27**. Here i have to check to which title, values are matching and can be grouped together within a tolorence limit of plus or minus *3%*. 
So in above example, *B value is in +-3% tolorence limit of A, hence A and B can be grouped together. C will not be grouped as its not in tolorence limit.*

Now if in addition to above values,i am having another title D with value 27.01 and E with value 26, then C and D should be grouped together as well.

```
Data:
---------------
Title   Values
---------------
A   27.32
B   27.33
C   27
D   27.01
E   26
```

**expecting result**

```
---------------
Title   Values
---------------
A,B Derived value in +-3% range of actual value(either title A or B)
C,D Derived value in +-3% range of actual value(either title C or D)
E   26
```

Above output will specify that for Titles A and B i can use derived value
and same goes for C and D as well. For title E, no match found and hence actual value will be used instead

Not able to derive logic for this. Though of creating range in +-3% tolorence limit and later to check for the actual value in created tolorence range.

Comment: Have already posted answer for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the correct values for a and b are 23.32 and 23.33 as started in the body of your question and not 27.32 and 27.33 like in the sample table (Because your desired results don't make sense otherwise), maybe something like this self join?

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN title_b IS NOT NULL THEN title_a || ',' || title_b
       ELSE title_a
       END AS Title
     , CASE WHEN title_b IS NOT NULL THEN 'Derived value in +-3% range of actual value(either title ' || title_a || ' or ' || title_b || ')'
       ELSE (SELECT value FROM data AS d WHERE d.title = title_a)
       END AS Value
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
         coalesce(min(l.title, r.title), l.title) AS title_a
       , max(l.title, r.title) AS title_b
      FROM data AS l
      LEFT OUTER JOIN data AS r ON l.title <> r.title
                               AND r.value BETWEEN l.value - (l.value * .03)
                                               AND l.value + (l.value * .03))
ORDER BY title_a;
```

Which, testing with sqlite (You didn't mention *which* database you're using, which is always useful to know), produces:

```
Title       Value                                                           
----------  ----------------------------------------------------------------
A,B         Derived value in +-3% range of actual value(either title A or B)
C,D         Derived value in +-3% range of actual value(either title C or D)
E           26
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick feedback. My bad , related to the input values discrepancy. Will try your way out for this problem. Even i tried something for this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I created a scaler function and used same in SQL query.

```
--SQL query:

Declare @a float=38.56,@b float,@c float,@freq float,@value float,@i int=0

while @i < (select count(distinct titles) from tableA) -- titles, a column name in tableA
begin
        select @freq=freq from tableA where id = @i+1
        begin
                set @b= @freq-(@freq*0.03)
                set @c=@freq+(@freq*0.03)
                if @a between @b and @c
                    begin
                        set @value = @freq
                        break
                    end
                else
                    begin
                        set @value =@a
                    end
        end 
    set @i=@i+1 
end
print convert(varchar,@value)
```

I can use same set of query for creating function which can accept one parameter as input. Now, will use function with my query something like **select *,function(@inputparameter) as derivedoutput from tableA**.